# Why is Join() adding multiple newlines between array elements?

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to c#. I need to remove the first line of a text file and then overwrite that file with the remaining text.

I can't get the output to match the original format:

```
MyFile:

This is unwanted line 0
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

When I try this:

```
string[] lines = pathToMyFile
    .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Skip(1)
    .ToArray();

// Using a newline as the separator
string myOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

MessageBox.Show(myOutput);
```

I get the following output:

```
This is line 1

This is line 2

This is line 3

This is line 4
```

But if I try this:

```
string[] lines = pathToFile
    .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Skip(1)
    .ToArray();

// Using "" instead of a newline as a separator
string myOutput = string.Join("", lines); 

MessageBox.Show(myOutput);
```

I get this:

```
This is line 1This is line 2This is line 2This is line 3This is line 4
```

How can I get this to output each line without whitespace between the lines?

Comment: `Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()` is splitting on CR and LF meaning that you have blank lines.

Comment: Try `\n` in join. `string myOutput = string.Join("\n", lines); `

Comment: @Dave I tried it but got the same result as when I used `Envrionment.NewLine`

Comment: Your file has line endings that ar a CR character followed by a LF character, that's pretty normal.  Just do `.Split(Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: A newline consists of 2 characters (on Windows at least) so it splits between those 2 characters as well, resulting in blank lines. You could try using the overload that takes `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` or don't use `ToCharArray()`

Comment: Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, it's probably better anyway.

Comment: Using StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries did the trick. Thank you. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidG That would remove any empty lines in the actual fine, which likely need to be preserved.

Comment: @Servy I'm aware, but no point telling me, it's OPs file, and they seem to be OK with it.

Comment: I would love to know why my question was downvoted so I can improve. I feel like although it's a simple answer it could be useful to others beginners that run into the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treate the `CrLf` string as a single "character" in your splitting (and want to preserve any existing blank lines), the  most backwards-compatible way is to use the [`string[] Split (string[], StringSplitOptions)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-2.0#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_):

```
string[] lines = pathToMyFile
    .Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Skip(1)
    .ToArray();
```